# Initialize heap array from other array

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I create an array on the heap and initialize it at construction time from another array?

```
template <typename T>
T* Copy(T* myOriginalArray, size_t myOriginalArraySize)
{
    T* copy = new T[myOriginalArraySize]; // copy data from myOriginalArray here too
    return copy;
}
```

I could create the array and then use std::copy, but this would require the array contents to have an empty constructor. You can assume the object has a copy and move constructor. I have access to C++17.

Comment: You should not return raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory from a function unless you love to debug memory leaks

Comment: Use `std::array`. It has a proper copy constructor already.

Comment: @Slava The function is only an example to show what I want to achieve, this is not production code.

Comment: @nwp std::array has a compile time size. I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Then use  `std::vector`

Comment: @Slava I am specifically trying to learn how to do this kind of stuff with arrays. std::vector is indeed what I would normally use for this purpose.

Comment: Arrays are C stuff, I doubt you could properly use move semantics with them.

Comment: @Slava Arrays are part of C++? There is no alternative as far as I know. In the end classes like `std::vector` are built using arrays. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think this can be done with placement new, `alignof` and some casting, but it would be hideously complicated to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Hm i feared so. I was hoping I was missing some form of notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `::operator new` and `std::uninitialized_copy`

```
#include<memory>
#include<new>

template<typename T>
T* Copy(T* src, size_t sz)
{
    auto buf = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * sz));
    std::uninitialized_copy(src, src + sz, buf);
    return buf;    
}
```

And possibly move, with a bit more hassle.

```
#include<utility>

template<typename T>
T* Move(T* src, size_t sz)
{
    auto buf = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * sz));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        new (buf + i) T(std::move(src[i]));
    return buf;
}
```

This is not really a great idea, considering then you have to deallocate with some crazy code

```
template<typename T>
void Delete(T* src, size_t sz)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        src[i].~T();
    ::operator delete(src);
}
```

Do consider using `std::vector` instead.

#### Side note

**Q:** Why index with `size_t` instead of using `T*`?
**A:** As it turns out, it is currently slightly faster with indexing.

Comment: This what I am looking for(the same as jdehesa's answer but more complete). Concern about destroying is righteous. Goal about question for me is learning how stuff like `std::vector` works internally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can just allocate the memory first and then use [placement `new`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) (which is basically what preallocating STL containers do anyway).

```
template <typename T>
T* Copy(T* myOriginalArray, size_t myOriginalArraySize)
{
    auto t_size = sizeof(T);
    T* copy = (T *) new char[myOriginalArraySize * t_size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < myOriginalArraySize; i++)
    {
        new (copy + i) T(*(myOriginalArray + i));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I do not, that the problem I tried to explain to OP

Comment: Actually I do think its possibly with some ugliness involved

Comment: The move thing confuses me. As far as I can see there is no moving involved. Array of objects is allocated without actual construction. Objects are constructed in place one by one using their copy constructor. Pointer to heap array is returned. Explanation of where move semantics are missing would be appreciated.